# One DOM element must be visible always on click event

Tags: jquery

I have some FAQ block with questions and answers. On `document` loaded all answers are hidden (`display: none`).

**1.** On click to question, the answer will `slideDown`.

**2.** On click to another question, the other answer will `slideDown` and current answer will `slideUp`

Now I need, at least 1 answer is always shown on page (when answer is shown, current answer won't `slideToggle`, how can I achieve that? (of course with JQuery library)

```js
$(function () {
    let answers = $('.answer');

    $('.faq .ask').on('click', slideAnswer);
    
    function slideAnswer() {
        let currentAnswer = $(this).next();
        currentAnswer.addClass('active');
        answers.not(currentAnswer).slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().stop(true).slideToggle(500, function () {
            if (currentAnswer.hasClass('active')) {
                currentAnswer.stop(true).slideUp;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
  

.item .ask {
    background: #ccc;
}  

.item .answer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="ask">1. Some question №1</div>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="ask">2. Some question №2</div>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor .</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="ask">3. Some question №3</div>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit .</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is the exact issue you are facing with your script here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't changed a lot to your given solution, just stopping the code if the `.answer` class contains `.active` class. Please check the code snippet

```js
$(function () {
    let answers = $('.answer');

    $('.faq .ask').on('click', slideAnswer);

    function slideAnswer() {
        let currentAnswer = $(this).next(),
            currentAnswerState = $(this).siblings('.answer');

        if (currentAnswerState.hasClass('active')) {
            return true;
        }

        currentAnswer.addClass('active');
        answers.not(currentAnswer).slideUp(500).removeClass('active');

        $(this).next().stop(true).slideToggle(500, function () {
            currentAnswer.stop(true).slideUp;
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.item .ask {
    background: #ccc;
}

.item .answer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="item">
      <div class="ask">1. Some question №1</div>
      <div class="answer">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <div class="ask">2. Some question №2</div>
      <div class="answer">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor .</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <div class="ask">3. Some question №3</div>
      <div class="answer">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit .</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: glad to help you (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$(function () {
   var answers = $('.answer');
    $('.faq .ask').on('click', function(){
        var currentAnswer = $(this).next('div.answer');
        answers.not(currentAnswer).slideUp(500);
        answers.not(currentAnswer).removeClass('active');
        currentAnswer.stop(true).slideToggle(500);
        currentAnswer.toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply slideUp all `answer` sections and only slideDown current question's sibling answer section as below:

```
$(document).on("click",".ask",function(){
    $(".answer").slideUp("500"),$(this).siblings(".answer").slideDown("500");
})
```